# How to store Carbon objects in MySQL using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

So, I know that Laravel stores their "created_at" and their "updated_at" as a Carbon object. At least, every time, I try to get them, the are returned as Carbon. So I have a Carbon object that I want to store in my "premium_until" column. Now, how should I go about doing this? Should I do `$table->timestamp('premium_until');` or `$table->date('premium_until');` when setting up the schema? Also, can I just do `$user->premium_until = $carbonObject;` or do I have to convert it to a string? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent offers convenient way to work with dates.
Just define `getDates` method on your Eloquent model, which returns array of column names which should be converted into `Carbon` instances automaticaly by Eloquent!

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array(static::CREATED_AT, static::UPDATED_AT, static::DELETED_AT, 'premium_until');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the `getDates` method, it is now possible to set the `$dates` attribute on your Eloquent model. The advantage over the previous answer is that you do not need to explicitly (re)define the Eloquent dates (e.g., `created_at`):

```
protected $dates = ['premium_until'];
```